# Retrieving data if control file is lost in oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle

Suppose if the databases control file is lost permanently (no backup).
Can we retrieve the data from data file in Oracle database?

Comment: Is there any problems with this question? (why it got a close(1))

Comment: It isn't a programming question, so it's been flagged as off-topic, and once enough people agree it will be migrated to [dba.se] where it will get more specialised attention. In the meantime, please update your question with details of your backup strategy, and indicate whether you have a [control file backup](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_1004.htm#i2089277) which would make this quite easy. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_5003.htm) may also be relevant later, but don't just dive in - you could easily make things worse.

Comment: Thank you, I am asking question in general, assuming the control file is permanently lost

Comment: Then in general - 'yes'. But the circumstances matter. If you know what should be in it then you can recreate it - see [here](http://myracle.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/recover-database-without-control-files-and-redo-log-files/) for example. Don't rely on this being possible though - it's no substitute for a real backup and recovery strategy.

Comment: Thank you, That's all I wanted to know. Can you put this as answer?

Comment: You have already asked this question on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29042/retrieving-data-if-control-file-is-lost-in-oracle-database). Please don't cross-post: you can ask a moderator to move your question with the flag link if you want your question to be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - 'yes'. But the circumstances matter. If you know what should be in the control file then you can recreate it (or rather, *them*; they should be multiplexed anyway) - see [this article](http://myracle.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/recover-database-without-control-files-and-redo-log-files/) for example. That uses the [`create controlfile` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_5003.htm) with appropriate options and parameters to recreate the control file matching your existing data files. Really make sure you understand what it's doing and what impact it may have - you don't want to make things worse than they already are.

Or [google for "oracle recover control file"](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=oracle+recover+control+file&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Don't rely on this being possible though - it's no substitute for a real backup and recovery strategy.